# Write data to pipe C++

Tags: c++, process, pipe, stdin

i need to do something like

```
echo "data" | cat
```

Using

```
echo "data" | my program
```

And inside my program calls the cat and sends my stdin to the cat stdin and get the stdout from the cat.

I already fork the process, close the write and the read, dup2 them and execl..
So i can get the stdout from it, if i do one execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", "ls -lahtr", NULL) i can get the file list as the output.

but i don't know how to send data, like send the echo data that i read from my stdin and send to the execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", "cat", NULL) stdin and return my echo string.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int ficheiro_fd;
    int pipe_fd[2];
    char buffer[20];
    int num_bytes;

    pipe(pipe_fd);

    switch ( fork() ) {
    case -1:
        exit(1);
    case 0:
        close(pipe_fd[1]);
        dup2(pipe_fd[0], 0);
        execlp("/usr/bin/base64"," ", NULL);
        break;
    default:
        close(pipe_fd[0]);
        //ficheiro_fd = open("output.txt", O_RDONLY);
    while ((num_bytes = read(fileno(stdin), buffer, 1)) > 0){
            write(pipe_fd[1], buffer, num_bytes);
            }
        close(pipe_fd[1]);
        wait((int*)getpid());
    }

    return 0;
}
```

With this code i can send some data to the program and it writes on the screen, i want to know how i can get the stdout and send to one variable.
Thanks for the help ppl.

Comment: It seems like you're doing something completely useless. Please show some code.

Comment: Can you share your code?  your question is a bit convoluted. In general a pipe is only one way, one process reads while the other writes, you cannot send data from the reader back to the writer over the same pipe.  So you can do echo data | your_prog | cat ... which will pass your program's stdout to cat's stdin...

Comment: Hi i shared the code, the reason i need that is i'm going to send one command trought socket and i need to process on the other side with my input and get the return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two pipe() calls before you fork.  Those will be the stdin and stdout of your called process.  After you fork, in the child process, dup2 the write end of one pipe to stdout (1) and the read end of the other pipe to stdin (0).  Close the unused ends of the pipe, then exec your process.

In the parent process, close the unused pipe fds.  You'll then have an fd that can be read from with read() corresponding to the child's stdout, and an fd that can be written to, corresponding to the child's stdin.

Comment: note, i need to send the data back trough a socket, how i get the data processed by execl?