# Do input redirection and capture command output (Custom shell-like program)

Tags: c++, multiprocessing, exec, dup2

I'm writing a custom shell where I try to add support for input, output redirections and pipes just like standard shell. I stuck at point where I cannot do input redirection, but output redirection is perfectly working. My implementation is something like this (only related part), you can assume that `(string) input` is non-empty

```cpp
void execute() {
... // stuff before execution and initialization of variables
int *fds;
std::string content;
std::string input = readFromAFile(in_file); // for input redirection

for (int i = 0; i < commands.size(); i++) {
        fds = subprocess(commands[i]);
        dprintf(fds[1], "%s", input.data()); // write to write-end of pipe
        close(fds[1]);
        content += readFromFD(fds[0]); // read from read-end of pipe
        close(fds[0]);
    }
... // stuff after execution
}


int *subprocess(std::string &cmd) {
    std::string s;
    int *fds = new int[2];
    pipe(fds);
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid == -1) {
        std::cerr << "Fork failed.";
    }
    if (pid == 0) {
        dup2(fds[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        dup2(fds[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        close(fds[1]);
        close(fds[0]);
        system(cmd.data());
        exit(0); // child terminates
    }
    return fds;
}
```

My thought is subprocess returns a pipe (fd_in, fd_out) and parent can write to write-end and read-from read-end afterwards. However when I try an input redirection something like `sort < in.txt`, the program just hangs. I think there is a deadlock because one waiting other to write, and other one to read, however, after parent writes to write-end it closes, and then read from read-end. How should I consider this case ?

When I did a bit of searching, I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8637118/7871601) answer, which my original thinking was similar except that in the answer it mentions creating two pipes. I did not quite understand this part. Why do we need two separate pipes ?

Comment: Input and output redirection should be done the same way. The only difference is that you open the file in read mode instead of write mode, and dup `STDIN_FILENO` instead of `STDOUT_FILENO`.

Comment: And the reason for using `new`, and having to deal with dynamic memory allocation, making sure to properly `delete` those brave, two integers, and avoiding memory leaks, versus simply returning a pair or a tuple of `int`s and not having to worry about any of that, would be what, exactly?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik yes, you are right. I changed that the return type of `subprocess()` to pair object.

Comment: @Barmar Can you please elaborate how you mean by opening a file in read mode instead of write ? Since I want to both read and write, shouldn't I dup both pipe ends ?

Comment: Input redirection means `command < filename`. So you do `fd = fopen(filename, O_RDONLY); dup2(STDIN_FILENO, fd); close(fd);`

Comment: Two pipes are needed, well, because standard input and output are two different file descriptors that have nothing to do with each other, whatsoever. The shown code creates a pipe and puts the same pipe on both file descriptors. The subprocess could write something on its standard output and immediately read it back on its own standard input. Does that make sense to you? And, adding to the fun: the parent process tries to read and write from the same pipe too. Hillarity ensues.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik well, I see. Since I'm a starter in OS, I was just thinking that one pipe would be enough for both stdin and stdout, with two pipes the problem now disappears it's resolved. Thank you for clarification.

Comment: @Barmar (for future readers) I think it should be `dup2(fd, STDIN_FILENO)` as the  `int dup2(int oldfd, int newfd)`.

Comment: That documentation always confuses me. I think of the "old" FD as the FD that was already open (e.g. stdin or stdout) and we want to replace with the "new" FD that we just opened.